# What is the best possible method to set the position of Mouse Pointer in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, cursor-position

I'm currently using `SetCursorPos(int x, int y)` to set the Cursor's position on my Canvas. This is my code which takes comma separated coordinates from a textbox and does some translation to convert it relative to my Canvas.

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{
    string[] s = setcoordinatesTB.Text.Split(", ".ToCharArray());
    if (s.Length != 2) return;
    int x,y;
    bool r1 = int.TryParse(s[0], out x);
    bool r2 = int.TryParse(s[1], out y);
    if (!(r1 && r2)) return;
    Point rel = canvas.TranslatePoint(new Point(x, y), window);
    SetCursorPos( x + (int)window.Left + 10 + (int)rel.X, y + (int)window.Top + 32 + (int)rel.Y);
}
```

Weird things are happening here..moments ago everything was working fine..(I have another text box which continuously displays cursor coordinates relative to my Canvas using `e.GetPosition(canvas)`). and on typing the desired mouse coord. & hitting enter, both the Textboxes were displaying the same coord (which should be). But **now**, when I type any coord. & hit enter, it becomes double of what it should. i.e. on typing 100,100 my cursor goes to 200,200 (which shows in the 2nd box). I divided the values by 2 to adjust, but then, cursor goes to another weird location which I cannot explain.

**PS**: If there's a better, surer way to set the Cursor's position (even if it's got a lot of hassle associated), please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first most obviouse question would be - what has changed between "moments ago" and now? Computer software usually doesn't change its output without something being altered.

But to help you debug, try out the following:

1. If you call the SetCursorPos with fixed values, does the mouse pointer go to the correct location?
2. Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger to see if all values are calculated as they should?
3. Have you checked whether both textboxes execute the same mouse cursor changing code? (from your problem description, I'd dare guess that something is **being executed twice**, thus the cursor location being **doubled**)